Unable to connect remote OPC-UA integration in thingsboard due to UNAVAILABLE: io exception
I am trying to add a remote OPC-UA integration on a server where ThingsBoard application is installed. I followed below steps:
1.Pulled the image of tb-pe-opc-ua-integration:3.6.4PE.
2.Created a volume for the integration logs.
3.Ran the integration with the host and port of the ThingsBoard server, along with INTEGRATION_ROUTING_KEY and INTEGRATION_SECRET
The integration fails to connect and repeatedly logs the following error:
2024-06-11 05:27:46,892 [main] INFO o.t.i.ThingsboardOpcUaIntegrationApplication - Started ThingsboardOpcUaIntegrationApplication in 5.435 seconds (JVM running for 6.792)
2024-06-11 05:28:06,652 [remote-integration-manager-service-reconnect-3-thread-1] INFO o.t.i.s.RemoteIntegrationManagerService - Trying to reconnect due to the error: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception!
2024-06-11 05:28:06,664 [remote-integration-manager-service-reconnect-3-thread-1] INFO o.t.i.rpc.IntegrationGrpcClient - [fgf777rl-90h9-hg89-d452-8rtgv381n4t4] Sending a connect request to the TB!
2024-06-11 05:28:09,652 [remote-integration-manager-service-reconnect-3-thread-1] INFO o.t.i.s.RemoteIntegrationManagerService - Trying to reconnect due to the error: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception!
2024-06-11 05:28:26,866 [remote-integration-manager-service-reconnect-3-thread-1] INFO o.t.i.rpc.IntegrationGrpcClient - [fgf777rl-90h9-hg89-d452-8rtgv381n4t4] Sending a connect request to the TB!
2024-06-11 05:28:26,867 [remote-integration-manager-service-reconnect-3-thread-1] INFO o.t.i.s.RemoteIntegrationManagerService - Trying to reconnect due to the error: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception!
I tried to set up the remote integration from my local desktop, but I am encountering the same error.
